# Heroku missing some changes after deploy

Tags: heroku

I've pushed some commits to Heroku and after getting an error and running `heroku run bash`, I see that some files are missing/have not been deployed. I think this might be due to some rebasing/pushing cycles I done before this deploy. I've already set up some addons so I'd like to avoid creating a new app and starting from scratch.

Is there an alternative way?

Edit:

The gist of what I did:

1. `rebase`
2. `push -f`
3. see errors on deploy..
4. more `rebase`-ing
5. `push -f`
6. see that files are missing from Heroku build

Answer (score 0):

You should check that all needed files are added to your Git repository and that there's nothing your app needs in `.gitignore` or `.slugignore`. Check this devcenter article for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Comment: they are, and, as a matter of fact, a few deploys earlier (I went through a few cycles of $ git rebase and $ git push heroku -f before I got to this state), Heroku wasn't picking up the changes in the config/routes.rb either (master's HEAD had a line which was missing in Heroku, thus causing routing errors)